# calculating total number of retweets in C#

Tags: c#, twitter, tweets

I am creating a web app in C#, and I want to calculate the total number of retweets to a user.

I found a lot of code snippets for calculating retweets for a [specfic tweet](https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=kool_aid_wino), but I want to calculate the total number of retweets to a user (without using OAuth). Has anyone done this type of work before?

Thanks in meekness.

Comment: have you checked the REST API?I belv there must be a call for that too..

Comment: Yes but that Didn't worked out

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done without OAuth.  They are pushing it hard.  Last time I was writing against the twitter API (using TweetSharp a year or so ago), I to get a consumer secret for the account I wanted to use, then use that to generate an OAuth handshake to get an access token.  I think you have to do it this way.  Why can't you use Oauth, it's quite nice actually.

Comment: @kmarks2  I just want to make it simple by making just simple calls.I believe there must be some way :)

Comment: @Mentor I understand completely.  I built a network messaging bus using Twitter and wanted to do it the simple way...and ended up being forced into doing it with OAuth.  If you read the docs it's really not that bad.  If I can remember to later I'll add a link to this post to my project.

Comment: @kmarks2 Thank you..that would surely be my last option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific API call for that - see the documentation for statuses/retweeted_to_user,
You can see the documentaion there as well,There are many free libraries available that can serve the purpose

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how many retweets the user has seen?

There is a specific API call for that - see the [documentation for statuses/retweeted_to_user](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_to_user)

Here are the last 100 retweets that people have sent me

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_to_user.xml?screen_name=edent&count=100
```

This method **does not** require OAuth

***EDIT*** Based on your answer...

You want to count how many time a user has retweeted.

You need to call the [user's timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and ensure you have include_rts=true

So, for example, to get the last 200 tweets I have sent

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=edent&count=200
```

Then, count the number of "retweeted_status".

Again, this doesn't require OAuth.

Comment: Do you mean "the number of times a user has retweeted" or "the number of retweets a user has seen"?